# Let $x$ and $y$ be two positive real numbers with $x < y$. Using only the axioms for real numbers, show that $0 < \frac{1}{y} < \frac{1}{x}$.

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

> Let $x$ and $y$ be two positive real numbers with $x < y$. Using only the axioms for real numbers, show that $0 < \frac{1}{y} < \frac{1}{x}$.

How can I prove this?

This is what I have so far:

$0 < x < y$ (definition of positive)

$0 < 1 < \frac{y}{x}$ (division by $x$)

$0 < \frac{1}{y} < \frac{1}{x}$ (division by $y$)

But I think it seems too simple.

Comment: This is what I have so far:
0 < x < y (definition of positive) 
0 < 1 < y/x (division by x) 
0 < 1/y < 1/x (division by y) 
but it seems too simple

Comment: What is your definition of $<$? What is your set of axioms of the real numbers?

Comment: Right on the dot actually! This works because $1/x$ is positive and by the axioms of the real numbers, multiplying by a positive number doesn't change the inequality.

Comment: Your proof is ok. Most of the proofs about elementary properties of real numbers are quite simple like this one.

Comment: @User7530 if m,n are in the set of all rational numbers, and m > n, then m-n is in the set of all natural numbers. For the axioms, I just meant the general ones, like commutativity, distributivity, operations, bounds, etc.

GPerez and Cure thanks for the comments! It seemed too good to be true, thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: How do you know that dividing by $x$ preserves the inequality?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x,y >0$ so that $x<y$ and for the sake of getting a contradiction assume that $\frac{1}{x}$ $\leq$ $\frac{1}{y}$. Then you get $x \geq y$, which means either $x=y$ or $x > y$. In either case you have a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$y>x$ means $y=x+M$ for some $M>0$.

$1/y>0$ is obvious: it's a ratio between positive numbers.

Then
$$
\frac1{y}=\frac1{x+M}=\frac1{x(1+\frac{M}{x})}=\frac1x\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{M}{x}}
$$

Next observe that $M,x>0$ hence $M/x>0$, thus $1+\frac{M}{x}>1$.

Now, by axioms of real numbers, the sign of an inequality is preserved is you multiply both sides by a positive quantity $c>0$. Let's multiply both sides of $1+\frac{M}{x}>1$ by the positive quantity $c=\frac{1}{1+\frac{M}{x}}$. We obtain then
$$
\frac{1}{1+\frac{M}{x}}<1.
$$

Hence you know that multiplying a positive quantity by a factor in $]0,1[$ you'll obtain something smaller (exercise). Thus
$$
\frac1x\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{M}{x}}<\frac1x
$$
as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

We will be working entirely with positive numbers in this answer.

$\quad x \lt y \text{ iff } (\exists \, u) \; x + u = y$

Multiplying both sides of this equation by the multiplicative inverse of $x$ and using the law of distributivity,

$\tag 1 x^{-1}x + x^{-1}u =  x^{-1}y$

Multiplying both sides of the equation $\text{(1)}$ by the multiplicative inverse of $y$ and using the law of distributivity,

$\tag 2 y^{-1} (x^{-1}x) + y^{-1}(x^{-1}u) =  y^{-1}(x^{-1}y)$

Using the laws of associativity and commutativity for multiplication,

$\tag 3 y^{-1} (x^{-1}x) + y^{-1}(x^{-1}u) =  x^{-1}(y^{-1}y)$

So,

$\tag 4 y^{-1} (1) + y^{-1}(x^{-1}u) =  x^{-1}(1)$

So,

$\tag 5 y^{-1}  + y^{-1}(x^{-1}u) =  x^{-1}$

With $v = y^{-1}(x^{-1}u)$ we have $y^{-1}  + v =  x^{-1}$, so, indeed, $y^{-1}  \lt x^{-1}$.